# PJSIP Undefined Symbols Architecture Armv7

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, sip, pjsip

I am trying to compile the [pjsip](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone) from  http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone.

```
cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ ./configure-iphone
$ make dep && make clean && make
```

I get following undefined symbols error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_pjmedia_avi_streams_get_num_streams", referenced from:
  _app_init in pjsua_app.o
  _reset_dev_info in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(avi_dev.o)
"_pjmedia_avi_streams_get_stream", referenced from:
  _app_init in pjsua_app.o
  _reset_dev_info in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(avi_dev.o)
"_pjmedia_vid_register_factory", referenced from:
  _pjmedia_avi_dev_create_factory in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(avi_dev.o)
"_pjmedia_vid_dev_get_local_index", referenced from:
  _pjmedia_avi_dev_get_param in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(avi_dev.o)
  _pjmedia_avi_dev_free in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(avi_dev.o)
"_pjmedia_vid_dev_get_global_index", referenced from:
  _pjmedia_avi_dev_alloc in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(avi_dev.o)
"_pjmedia_avi_player_create_streams", referenced from:
   _pjmedia_avi_dev_alloc in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(avi_dev.o)
"_pjmedia_avi_streams_get_stream_by_media", referenced from:
  _pjmedia_avi_dev_alloc in libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a(avi_dev.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjsua-arm-apple-darwin9] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pjsua] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Please help in compiling this project in for Xcode 4.3.

Comment: add this to your pre processor macros in build settings PJ_AUTOCONF

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a library that you should be linking against. From the symbol errors it looks like it might be called pjmedia. Make sure you are linking against all the libraries. precompiled o files that pjsip requires